# What does kCIInputCenterKey parameter control in CIPixellate filter?

Tags: ios, image-processing, core-image

The only [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIPixellate) I can find doesn't say much:

> A CIVector object whose attribute type is CIAttributeTypePosition and
>   whose display name is Center.

I did some experiment. I can see it shift some "center". But I want to know what exactly it controls in the underlining pixelation algorithm so that I can use it in a knowledgeable way instead of blindly fumbling.

Answer (score 1):

I think it shifts where the initial sampling point is taken, so that combined with the scale parameter will adjust which pixels are pulled out for the pixelate.

You can try it out in QuartzComposer (or even Acorn (an app written by myself)) and futz around with the parameters to get a good idea as to what it does.

Comment: Looks like it, but I'm not 100% certain.